# Change image size of group heading in objectlistview

Tags: c#, objectlistview

How do I change the size of the images shown in the group headings?

The images I use are bitmap and larger than 16x16. Yet they are shown in 16x16.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that the size can be set by accessing `ImageList.ImageSize`. Make sure you set that property on the imagelist before you attach it to the `ObjectListView.GroupImageList`.

Example:

```
ImageList imgList = new ImageList();
imgList.ImageSize = new Size(x, y);

//Add [key/img] to the list.

this.objectListView.GroupImageList = imgList;
```

For some reason you cannot set the `objectListView.GroupImageList.ImageSize` directly, it won't show the images at all.
I'm not experienced enough to understand why this is not possible.